# Run .net core console app on linux with supervisor

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I have a simple console application: there is a loop that processes data coming from an external source. 
When I run it in bash with the command dotnet MyApp.dll all right, but when it starts supervisor, in log have errors:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected. Try Console.Read.
at System.ConsolePal.ReadKey(Boolean intercept)
at Crawler.Test.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

but in the main method, I have no call "Console.ReadKey" or something like.

I'm trying to do something like daemon.

My supervisor conf

```
[program:dotnetapp]
directory = /var/app/MyApp
command = /bin/bash -c "dotnet /var/app/MyApp/MyApp.dll"
numprocs = 1
autostart = true
autorestart = true
user=www-data
```

Main

```
using (MyDisposableClass myClass = new MyDisposableClass())
{
    myClass.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("App started...");
}
```

Comment: So what's in your `Main`? Whatever you call could indirectly be invoking `ReadKey` (and still not be present in the stack trace due to inlining optimizations).

Comment: ...so what's in `myClass.Start()`, and then what's in the methods *it* calls? Let me cut this short: find the place in the code (either yours or a library's) where `.ReadKey` is getting called. That such a place exists is a guarantee, per the stack trace, it may just be tricky to find. Turning off all optimizations may help here (I don't know how you do that in .NET Core on Linux.)

Comment: no one ReadKey/Line/etc. No one console call

Comment: any way to fix that problem?